# Symfony - prePersist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, persist, listeners

The prePersist is not fired.

```
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $gateway =  /* ... some logic here ... */

    $person = new User();
    $person->setName('Bruno');
    $person->setEmail('bruno_nonato_quaresma@hotmail.com');
    $person->setPassword(md5('some-one'));       
    $person->setMembersArea($gateway->getProject()->getMembersArea());
    $person->setActive(true);  

    $manager->persist($person);
    $manager->flush();
```

My config.yml

```
 mymembers.listener.generateUsername:
    class: MYmembers\AdminBundle\EventListener\UsernameGenerator
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

UsernameGenerator class method

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof User) 
    {
        $this->setUsername($entity, $entityManager);    
    }
}
```

The strange is that in the fixtures the UsernameGenerator is called but when i do the SAME code in the controller not works... :(

Comment: It looks right and the fact that it gets called from a fixture suggests you have it wired up correctly.  Make sure your controller code is actually being executed?